# N 3d integer points in box with maximum average distance

Tags: search-algorithms

given a 3d cube with a size of m x m x m, is there an efficient algorithm to find N integer points with the average Euclidean distance between each pair maximized? If not, is there any evolutionary approach I can take to this, so in each step the solution will be improved?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll get a pretty good solution if you choose $N$ points at random.

Answer (score 1):

Note that maximizing the average distance between every pair of points is the same as maximizing the total distance between every pair of points.

Let's look at an m x m square first. When N = 4, it is clear that the optimal solution is placing a point in each corner.

For N = 5, the next picture explores two alternatives of placing the 5th point when the other 4 are in the corners. It appears it is optimal to place the 5th point also in a corner. Note that in the right picture, which is already sub-optimal, the total solution does not improve when moving any of the other four points (which are in the corners).

[image: solution in a square]

This solution does not work for all N, but it generalizes to cubes when N is a multiple of 8. Then all points are in the eight corners in an optimal solution.

Comment: 1. For 5 points, it appears you are assuming that it is optimal to place 4 of the points in a corner.  What if there is a better solution that does not involve having at least 4 points in a corner?  2. For cubes, you propose a solution when $N$ is a multiple of 8.  How do you know that it is optimal, and that there is no better solution?

Comment: @D.W. I agree these "proofs" are sloppy, but I challenge anyone to find a counterexample to the claims. Indeed, in 2d for N=5 it is optimal to place all points in corners. In 2d it may only not hold for N = 3 mod 4. And in 3d when N is a multiple of 8, it is optimal to place all points in corners.